# VBA- Replacing Data and Creating new Documents

Tags: excel, vba

So I'm trying to load a word templatee, then populate that template with data, and finally then save it as a word or PDF document based on the filepath from a cell.

I have 4 other macros, one for populating data into the sheet from a template, and then 3 for selecting the save location, invoice template, and data source respectively.

I think there's something off with the Dim WordContent As WordRange, but after enabling Microsoft Office, Excel, Forms, and Word 16.0 Object library, the compile error disappeared.

Kinda stuck- not sure why its not creating/saving the word documents. The original invoice template is also not being overwritten, so I don't really know whats going on wrong.

It shows that word pops up, and it closes after it's done, but nothing gets saved..

```
    Sub CreateTaxReceipt()
Dim CustRow, CustCol, LastRow As Long
Dim DocLoc, TagName, TagValue, FileName As String
Dim CurDt, LastAppDt As Date
Dim WordDoc, WordApp As Object
Dim Path1 As String
Dim WordContent As Word.Range
With Sheet1

 If .Range("B3").Value = Empty Then
MsgBox "Please select an Invoice template from the drop down list"
.Range("G3").Select
Exit Sub
 End If

If .Range("B4").Value = Empty Then
MsgBox "Please select Data from the drop down list"
.Range("G4").Select
Exit Sub
  End If

  If .Range("B5").Value = Empty Then
MsgBox "Please select Save Location from the drop down list"
.Range("G5").Select
Exit Sub
 End If



'Open Word Template
On Error Resume Next 'If Word is already running
Set WordApp = GetObject("Word.Application")
If err.Number <> 0 Then
'Launch a new instance of Word
err.Clear
'On Error GoTo Error_Handler
Set WordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
WordApp.Visible = True 'Make the application visible to the user
End If


LastRow = .Range("E9999").End(xlUp).Row  'Determine Last Row in Table
    For CustRow = 8 To LastRow
                            Set WordDoc = WordApp.Documents.Open(FileName:=DocLoc, ReadOnly:=False) 'Open Template
                            For CustCol = 5 To 14 'Move Through 8 Columns
                                TagName = .Cells(7, CustCol).Value 'Tag Name
                                TagValue = .Cells(CustRow, CustCol).Value 'Tag Value
                                 With WordDoc.Content.Find
                                    .Text = TagName
                                    .Replacement.Text = TagValue
                                    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
                                    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll 'Find & Replace all instances
                                 End With
                            Next CustCol
                    If .Range("I3").Value = "PDF" Then
                                    Path1 = Range("B5")
                                   FileName = Path1 & "\" & .Range("F" & CustRow).Value & ".pdf" 'Create full filename & Path with current workbook location, Last Name & First Name
                                   WordDoc.ExportAsFixedFormat OutputFileName:=FileName, ExportFormat:=wdExportFormatPDF
                                   WordDoc.SaveAs FileName
                                   WordDoc.Close False
                               Else: 'If Word
                                  Path1 = Range("B5")
                                   FileName = Path1 & "\" & .Range("F" & CustRow).Value & ".docx"
                                   WordDoc.SaveAs FileName
                               End If
    Next CustRow
    WordApp.Quit
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Change `'On Error GoTo Error_Handler` to `On Error GoTo 0` and uncomment. Then rerun and see if you get any error messages.

Comment: Thanks for responding!

hmm nope, no errors, still same as before- shows it runs on the background then nothing happens

I also tried to add '              WordDoc.SaveAs FileName
                                       WordDoc.Save' 

but nothing happens either way.

Comment: Add a breakpoint on `WordDoc.SaveAs`  Does your code reach that line, and if it does, is `FileName` what you expect?

Comment: Oh that's itneresting. After adding the breakpoint, it shows Word opens, but it's blank. No filenames, nothing is getting replaced, and even my invoice word template isn't loading.